# Select all children of last div with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a `jQuery` `menu` that, when a user clicks a .item div on the last .menu div, another .menu div should be created below with other .item divs. Then, only those divs may be clicked (if there are any) to possibly generate other .menu divs (with possibly another .item divs).

Basically, I need the `jQuery` `selector` which selects all .item divs inside last .menu div only.

I tried the following with no success:

```
$('.menu:last').children('.item').on("click",function(){
  $('body').append("<div class=\"menu\"><div class=\"item\"><svg><text x=\"50%\" y=\"50%\" dy=\".3em\">Vehicles</text></svg></div></div>");
});
```

and this did not work as well:

```
$('.menu:last-child .item').on("click",function(){
  $('body').append("<div class=\"menu\"><div class=\"item\"><svg><text x=\"50%\" y=\"50%\" dy=\".3em\">Vehicles</text></svg></div></div>");
});
```

Here is the fiddle with the html and css code:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZpGe/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the click to be dynamically on the last menu you must use event-delegation like this

```
$(document).on('click','.menu:last .item',function(){
          $('body').append("<div class=\"menu\"><div class=\"item\"><svg><text x=\"50%\" y=\"50%\" dy=\".3em\">Vehicles</text></svg></div></div>");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/2ZpGe/2/)

Comment: @MagisterMundus It doesn't have to be inside a DOM ready handler since it's delegated on document.